# Is there a faster alternative to Selenium's send_keys in python 3?

Tags: python, file, selenium, text, sendkeys

I have automated a task which fills in a web form from a text file. This text file can grow quite big and using the send_keys() function in selenium + python3 takes quite a while.

Is there a much faster alternative, much like how copy/paste works?

This is how I'm using it in my script:

```
reportFile = open(reportFilePath,'r')

for line in reportFile.read():
    messageElem.send_keys(line)
reportFile.close()
```

I have looked online and there are alternatives but only in JS. I am looking for a faster way of adding the text from the file specifically with python 3.

Comment: It is quiet unclear what you are asking. why are you sending individual characters, while you can send lines and there is also possibility to convert the whole file at once and send as string

Comment: In Selenium's Java and Javascript Client API, sendKeys() accept an string  array as argument, so you read the file into lines and only one time to call send_keys(lines). or read file into a single string, then call one time send_keys(content).   If all above not faster as you want, you can try use python to  execute command to open the report file with text editor installed on machine, focus on text editor, use CTRL + A and CTRL +C, then focus on the input box on page, send_keys(CTRL+V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indeed,  Visweswaran Nagasivam was correct. I was reading the file character by character. The proper method for me would have been to use readlines() function:

```
#open the report file
reportFile = open(reportFilePath,'r')

#iterate over each line of the report file and fill in the message body
for line in reportFile.**readlines**():
    messageElem.send_keys(line)

#close the file 
reportFile.close()
```